# The max apiVersion is 44.0 error

Tags: trailhead, vs-code

Trying to work through the [Quick Start: Lightning Web Components trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components) and getting the following error while running command:

```
force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias HelloWorldLightningWebComponent --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername
```

> ERROR:  The configured apiVersion 45.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 44.0.

I did not set up a new dev hub environment, but rather enabled devhub in my old dev environment. 
Tried updating sfdx-project.json to include "sourceApiVersion": "44.0". but no luck.

Comment: The Spring '19 pre-release signup is now live. Updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Just got an update that the Spring '19 pre-release signup link is now live. You can access it on [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring19.jsp).

---

You are getting this error because the LWC project expects a version 45.0 (Spring '19 pre-release org), whereas the current DE sandboxes are still on version 44.0 (Winter '19).

You will need to signup for the Spring '19 pre-release DE Org to be used as DevHub for this module. And as of now that's not available, unless you already have a sandbox which has been upgraded to Spring '19.

I was in same situation this morning and found out that the signup for pre-release DE Org is not live yet. Refer to this [tweet](https://twitter.com/jayantkdas/status/1073225645788925957) for response from Salesforce.

Comment: Yeah, the trailhead kind of fails to mention this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @sfdcfox True. I actually was exactly in this situation when went back and realized I need a Spring '19 org for this module. Then while signing up, couldn't do so.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying a trailhead this morn. I think LWC is going to change the way we do things, but a bit annoying they announced it without specifying special hoops

Comment: I could just imagine, there's a lot of excitement around it from this morning, the time it was announced. I think I haven't seen anything like this which is *GA* without releasing a *beta* in first place.

Comment: That's because they've been secretly testing it for a year. I noticed it a few months ago and I wrote it off as some Aura oddity, but I've known about this for a while. Like you'll write a component that uses `lightning:button`, but if you debug it in the Lightning Debugger, it shows up as a `lightning-button`, basically a first-class citizen of Lightning, which struck me as odd.

Comment: The pre-rel sign up is live: https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring19/

Sign up for a DE account there, set it as your Dev Hub and you should be good to go.