# Not being able to access previous Developer Edition Account after creating and logging in to the new pre-release edition

Tags: salesforcedx

I was setting up SalesforceDX and creating a SFDX project in VS code and I had run into an issue with folowing error while trying to create default scratch org:

> ERROR: The configured apiVersion 45.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 44.0.

I followed the answer in this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/242504/62146) and created a new account of the pre-release edition(developer edition type). Then I set it up as my dev hub account.
But now I can't login to my old developer account. I can only access my new account. When I run the command:

> sfdx force:org:list

I get following output:
[image] 
The first one is my older developer account and the second one is my new pre-release developer account.

Any help on how I can access my old account again?

Edit: I could create a scratch org after enabling the Dev hub in from the salesforce.org setup. And now I can start creating lightning web components but now if I go to the login page of salesforce.org, I can no longer login using my older account. I can only login using the account of the type pre-release edition Spring '19.

Comment: I linked my previous Q&A for you. You need to create a project, and then provide an API override. This will allow you to use your Winter '19 orgs.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for a quick reply. the dev hub is now linked to my second(new) account. I've set the version to 44.0 like you said in the other thread but I get and ERROR: You do not have access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] object

Comment: Your Dev Hub org needs a custom permission set, and you need to assign it to the developers. This information is [in the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm).

Comment: I was able to create scratch org after enabling dev hub from the setup in salesforce. My main issue now is how do I log in to the developer account I was using prior to creating this new account of the type pre-release edition. I can only access the pre-release edition account but not the old account.

Comment: As long as you're in API 44.0 mode, it should work just fine. That's the setup I'm using right now. You'll know it is correct when you see: `WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at 44.0
Access org 00D... as user abc@xyz.com with the following URL: https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=session-key`

Comment: Yes I can now start working on the project. The problem regarding the creating of scratch org is resolved. The issue I have now is that I cant login to the salesforce.org using my old account. I can only login using the new account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88282/discussion-between-aanchal-adhikari-and-sfdcfox).